# MVP pattern temporary data storage

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-mvp

I am working on an application in which different screens need to load data from API. Like there is a details screen that needs to load data from API on the basis of **id** passed to it. I am passing **id** to fragment in bundle created by newInstance method. I am implementing my app according to MVP pattern and am a bit confused that where should I store this **id** in view or presenter. I also need some temporary variables to keep track of whether data was loaded or not because I am loading data on onStart event on fragment

Comment: no simple data in form of POJO classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you should store **id** in presenter.

Anyway you load data from API inside presenter. If you need to get that **id** in Activity you can get if from presenter.